# Very slow upload speed with nginx proxying apache

Tags: apache-2.2, nginx

I have a nginx server proxying apache on my server, and the setup has been running fine... Until yesterday, when I found out that, actually, uploading a file using a PHP script is very slow. Since uploading directly using Apache (on another port) is still lightning fast, I've come to a conclusion that the nginx+apache duo is the culprit. Problem is, I don't know how to fix it...

This is my nginx.conf

```
user apache;
worker_processes 16;
error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    server_tokens off;
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    server_names_hash_bucket_size 128;
    sendfile        on;
    tcp_nopush     on;
    keepalive_timeout  65;
    tcp_nodelay        on;
    gzip              on;
    gzip_comp_level   5;
    gzip_http_version 1.0;
    gzip_min_length   0;
    gzip_types        text/plain text/css image/x-icon application/x-javascript;
    gzip_vary         on;

    client_header_timeout 10m;
    client_body_timeout 10m;
    send_timeout 10m;

    fastcgi_read_timeout 600;
    fastcgi_send_timeout 600;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

My proxy.conf file looks like this:

```
proxy_redirect          off;
proxy_set_header        Host            $host;
proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Protocol  $scheme;
client_max_body_size    500m;
client_body_buffer_size 256k;
client_header_buffer_size 1k;
proxy_connect_timeout   1200s;
proxy_send_timeout      1200s;
proxy_read_timeout      1200s;
proxy_buffer_size       128k;
proxy_buffers           4 256k;
proxy_busy_buffers_size 256k;
```

And, if it matters, the iptable rules:

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     udp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           udp dpt:20
ACCEPT     udp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           udp dpt:21
ACCEPT     udp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           udp dpt:53
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:20000
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:10000
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:443
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:80
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:993
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:143
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:995
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:110
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:20
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:21
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:53
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:587
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:25
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:22

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

Also, it's curious that uploading via nginx proxying thin (Ruby on Rails) is still normal. Problem only happens with those Apache+nginx, not anything else.

Have any of you guys experienced this before? Thanks in advance.

EDIT: To give more details, for a 8MB file, Chrome status bar reveals that uploading the first 15% always happens really fast. The progress then proceeds to slow down to forever.

Comment: That's a too vague issue. You give us a configuration excerpt and describe your problem with almost no precise element. Please edit your question in order to post factual information like full nginx configuration, firewall rules, nginx/apache logs etc.

Comment: @XavierLucas You're right, apologies. I've updated the question.

Comment: if you use lo0 to communicate between nginx and apache
try
ifconfig lo0 mtu 1500